# Default size of std::queue when creating it by malloc

Tags: c++, vector, queue

When creating a pointer to `std::queue` and allocating memory for it using `malloc`, I found that the default size of queue was not zero as in the following code:

```
#include <queue>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    std::queue <int> * received_queue = NULL;

    received_queue = (std::queue <int > *) malloc (sizeof (std::queue <int>));

    printf ("%d\n", received_queue -> size ());
}
```

The result returned is: 4294967168 where I expected to get zero.

I replaced queue with vector, so the code becomes:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    std::vector <int> * received_vector = NULL;
    received_vector = (std::vector <int > *) malloc (sizeof (std::vector <int>));

    printf ("%d\n", received_vector -> size ());
}
```

The result returned now is 0.

My question: Is there something I have missed in allocating `std::queue`?

Comment: this is C++ code, not C. please update tags

Comment: I almost don't differ between all syntax of C and C++, so I used printf and malloc to indicate that this is C code. What is still now C++?

Comment: @Mohamad-jaafar: std::vector and std::queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc` allocates a memory block, but *does not actually construct an object there*, so it will contain garbage. This is one of the reasons you should use `new` in C++ instead.

If you replace the `malloc` call with `new std::queue<int>` then you will see the expected result.

If, for some weird reason, you need to construct an object in the memory block, you can use "placement `new`":

```
new(received_vector) std::vector<int>;
```

and also remember to call the destructor yourself before calling `free` (since `free` doesn't call destructors either).

Comment: Thank you, I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way to create objects in C++. In fact, it is Undefined Behaviour.

Do it with the `new` operator, like this:

```
std::vector<int> * received_vector = new std::vector<int>;
std::queue<int> * received_queue = new std::queue<int>;
```

Then the newly created objects will be properly constructed (initialized), because `new` causes their constructors to be executed.